# How to paste image(s) when creating a PR in VSTS?

Tags: azure-devops

When I'm **creating** a pull request (PR) in VSTS, in the description field I can't paste images. After the PR is created I can **edit** the description and then I can paste images. Is this a bug/missing feature?

[image: Can't paste an image here]

[image: Can paste here]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

> this feature was released in Sprint 177

[Source](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/paste-images-when-creating-a-pr/899842)

---

> Pasting a file/image is not allowed now when creating a PR.

From Marina's comment in [her answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45952821/185123).

> And I [posted a UserVoice entry for it.](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/899842/paste-images-when-creating-a-pr.html)

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not a bug or missing feature.

Pictures are allowed for the PR description region. You need to obey the **Markdown syntax**:

```
![Text](URL)
```

**For the picture located on the web,** the example is below:

```
![web picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mI2PX.png)
```

**For the picture located on a local machine**, you should use Base64 to encode the local picture and use the encoded URL for the PR description.

You can use the [online tool](https://www.base64-image.de/) to encode your local picture: select a local picture/image, encode the image, show code, copy to clipboard, and use it in this syntax:

[image]

```
![local](data:image/png;base64,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)
```

And no matter where the pictures come from (web or local), all of them can be shown in PR description.

[image]

[image]

---

Yes, it can’t paste a file/image when creating a PR, but it can drag/drop/paste or select files/images when editing the PR description.

As the message, only hints **Markdown supported** in the PR creation page. Drag & drop, paste, or select files to insert.** in the PR description editing page.

It can be improved. I posted a user voice [Drag & drop, paste, or select feature for PR description is missing](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/899842/paste-images-when-creating-a-pr.html). Feel free to vote and follow up.

Comment: thanks Marina, please see my updated question.  why can't I paste when I'm creating only editing?

Comment: Yeah, thanks for your feedback. Paste a file/image does not allowed now when creating a PR. And I posted an user voice for it. You can find the detail in the end of my answer.

Comment: This bites.  If I had permissions to update a wiki in Devops without having to do it in a repository, it wouldn't be a problem at all.  But now I have to jump through hoops to get a simple image pasted into a wiki.

Answer (score -1):

You can indeed paste images. I snipped a part of my screen using the Snip tool in windows. Ctrl + C to copy it and pasted it
[image]

Comment: That looks like you're editing.  I'm talking about during creation.  I add some screenshots to my question.